# firebase authentication in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

is it possible in firebase to create an account with both email password and phone  authentication such that user can sign in with either of them. I tried linkWithCredential method but it is not working

Comment: Are you following [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking)?

Comment: yes i did but it is showing error in phoneauthprovider line

Comment: Is not working why? Please add some code.

Comment: i got it to work but thanks for input